# Infinity-categorical exceptional push-forward

Tags: reference-request, sheaf-theory, infinity-categories

Classically, if $f:X\to Y$ is a map of locally compact Hausdorff topological spaces, one can define the exceptional push-forward functor $f_!:Sh(X;k)\to Sh(Y;k)$ among $k$-valued sheaves for, say, a field $k$. Then one can form the derived functor to obtain a functor amond derived categories, take the right adjoint and get Verdier duality out of this.

Is there's a place where the functor $f_!$ is constructed on the level of infinity categories of sheaves, along with some of the basic properties it should have (e.g. functoriality for composition, identification for open embeddings, e.t.c)? I found a treatment for $\ell$-adic sheaves in some sources, but couldn't find a reference for this, much simpler probably, context.

Comment: Does section 5.5.5 of Higher Algebra help? (this establishes Verdier duality, and I think one can recover the exceptional pushforward by combining duality with the usual pushforward, right?)

Comment: @DylanWilson well yes, in principle it does because I can define $f_! = Df_*D$. Thanks. Still I hoped that somewhere there is a direct development of it as a colimit over proper subsets or so, but for my needs it should suffice I guess.

Comment: It seems like such a development follows from the description in Proposition 5.5.5.10

Comment: sure, I mean, formally it is the case where $f$ is the projection to the point but I guess that this together with one extra bit of functoriality of the construction suffices. Thanks.

Comment: I think Xin Jin worked out the details in chapter 3 of the paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06708.

Comment: @Chris Kuo yes its exactly what I was looking for thanks!